# Angular Http post request can't reach C# endpoint

Tags: c#, angular, http, httprequest

I wrote a Http-Post request to update data in my C#-Backend. I can't figure out why it's not working bc every other http-request in my project works.

Angular Service Code:

```
private RestApiURL = 'https://localhost:44360/api/categories/';

public addCategory(category: Category) {
    return this.httpClient.post<Category>(this.RestApiURL + "addCategory", category);
}
```

C# Backend code:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]/")]
public class CategoriesController : Controller
{

    ... other code

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("addCategory")]
    public Category AddCategory(Category category)
    {
        var cat = new Category()
            {
                Id = new Guid(),
                Representation = category.Representation,
                RoomCount = category.RoomCount
            };
        _context.Categories.Add(cat);

        _context.SaveChanges();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: For future explanation: I'm getting now a 500-Server Error. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the Docs. of serving a Angular-App here: https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server

you need to create a proxy.conf.json in the root-directory of your Angular Project. The proxy.conf.json should look like this:

```
{
    {
    "/api": {
        "target": "https://localhost:44360/api",
        "pathRewrite": {"^/api": ""},
    }
}
```

In your service you need to change your current code to:

```
return this.httpClient.post<Category>("/api/categories/addCategory",category);
```

Now you need to serve your angular-project with: `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`.
Angular will now Proxy your request to your Backend.

Here is some further reading why you are getting this error https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors.

Comment: My Post-Request still doesn't work. All the other requests to the server work. I don't have any Cors errors.

Comment: i forgot a forward slash in the return statement, i edited my answer, can you try it again?

Comment: nice, can you mark it as answer if everything works?